# Owl carousel 2: Lazy load for videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel-2

I have a carousel powered by Owl carousel v2 with lazy load enabled:

JS:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  lazyLoad: true
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div>
   <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="...">
  </div>
</div>
```

which works OK. Then I tried to apply the same code to the HTML5 video tags I have:

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div>
   <video>
     <source class="owl-lazy" data-src="..." type="video/mp4">
   </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

which didn't work. Any ideas how to enable it for videos too?

Comment: Have you checked the docs to see if that is even implemented for videos? If not, you might need to implement it yourself. Plus, it probably needs pausing the currently playing video when switching to another slide as well.

Comment: @CBroe, Yes, I did and hoped I missed something. I dont' see any reason why owl carousel wouldn't replace `data-src` with `src` for the `source` tag instead if `img`, but this is how it works it seems.

Answer (score 2):

If anybody came accross the same issue, the solution I came up with is below:

```
// Lazy load for videos
var modalSlider = $('.owl-carousel');

modalSlider.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
  var current = event.item.index;
  var currentVideo = $(event.target).find('.owl-item').eq(current).find('video');
  var currentVideoSource = currentVideo.find('source');

  // Pause all videos
  var videos = modalSlider.find('video');

  if ( videos.length ) {
    videos.each(function() {
      $(this)[0].pause();
    });
  }

  // Play if video found
  if ( currentVideo.length ) {
    var currentVideoSrc = currentVideoSource.attr('data-src');
    currentVideoSource.attr('src', currentVideoSrc);
    currentVideo[0].load();
    currentVideo[0].play();
  }
});
```